# Avoid double quotes for varchar or char columns while exporting to csv file from oracle using utl_file_nchar

Tags: oracle, csv

I'm using UTL_FILE_NCHAR to export data to csv files.
How can we avoid double quotes from varchar and char columns when exporting data to csv files from oracle 11g database table.

Comment: `UTL_FILE_NCHAR` isn't a built-in package; possibly you are referring to nchar handling within [`UTL_FILE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-EBC42A36-EB72-4AA1-B75F-8CF4BC6E29B4), but it doesn't look like a typo, and you then talk about char and varchar, not nchar. Maybe you have your own wrapper package or procedure; and that is adding quotes, as Oracle won't do that automatically? Some tools will of course, but it doesn't sound like you're relying on a particular tool's export functionality.

Comment: let me clear, In my oracle database table I'm having columns of type char and varchar. I'm using UTF_FILE_NCHAR such that the data will be exported in utf-8 or binary file format when I export to csv's but not as default database characterset. Now, my concern is that those char and varchar columns which becomes of type nchar is coming in double quotes in csv's . I would like to avoid those double quotes. Hope now, the question is clear

Comment: Please add information to your question; and show the (minimal) code you are using to create and populate the file. I still don't know what `UTF_FILE_NCHAR` is.